# Python beginner here - having issue with a for loop working within a class definition

Tags: python, class, for-loop

My code displays this:

"Here are the administrator's privileges:
- ('block users', 'add new users')"

But I would like for it to display this way:

"Here are the administrator's privileges:

- Blocks users

- Add new users"

I've tried messing around with the formatting (vague sorry!) within show_privileges() and tried adding a for loop within show_privileges, and that has not worked. I've tried to define 'privilege in privileges' in other places but that has not worked.

(a lesson from P.C.C)

```
class User:
    """Create a user profile."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, city, phone_number):
        """Initialize attributes of the user profile."""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.city = city
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def describe_user(self):
        """Summarize user profile."""
        print(f"\n{self.first_name} {self.last_name} is {self.age} years old and lives in {self.city}.") 
        print(f"You can contact {self.first_name} at {self.phone_number}.")

    def greet_user(self):
        """Print a personal greeting to the user."""
        print(f"Hi {self.first_name}, glad you are here!")

class Privileges:
    """A simple attempt to model privileges for an administrator."""

    def __init__(self, *privileges):
        """Initialize attributes of privileges."""
        super().__init__(*privileges)

    def privileges(self, *privileges):
        """Store a list of the administrator's privileges."""
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        """Print a list of administrator privileges."""
        print("Here are the administrator's privileges:")
        print(f"- {self.privileges}")

class Admin(User):
    """Represents aspects of a user, specific to an administrator."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, city, phone_number):
        """Initialize attributes from the parent class."""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, city, phone_number)
        self.privileges = Privileges()

user_jane = Admin('jane', 'doe', 35, 'new york city', 5555551234) <br />
user_jane.privileges.privileges('block users', 'add new users') <br />
user_jane.privileges.show_privileges()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you override your `self.privileges` in your code with the function `def privileges(self, *privileges):`

But for your problem, you can do a for loop on those privileges

as this:

```py
    def show_privileges(self):
        """Print a list of administrator privileges."""
        print("Here are the administrator's privileges:")
        for p in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {p}")
```

Comment: @ChristinaBoak no problem :), consider mark it as currect answer if you think so